# Is it possible to parse xml not by file name but its content (string value)?

Tags: java, xml

Good Day,
Is it possible to parse XML content by not using its absolute path?

So it goes like this I have two variables:

```
replyInXml = "<company><staff id="1001"><firstname>yong</firstname><lastname>mook kim</lastname><nickname>mkyong</nickname><salary>100000</salary></staff></company>"

xmlFilePath = "c:\folder\file.xml"
```

In my Java code, I use the absolute path and I got the xml result I wanted. My question is, is it possible to parse it using the converted xml string (**replyInXml**) variable above.

```
File fXmlFile = new File(xmlFilePath);
```

Full Code:

```
public class XmlReader {
public String showProcessFlowID(String replyInXML) {
    String processFlowResult = "";
    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File(replyInXML);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("SUIFT:TEST_ATTR_LIST");

        // System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                String processStep = "PROCESS STEP=" + eElement.getElementsByTagName("SUIFT:TEST_STAGE").item(0).getTextContent();
                String flowID = "FLOW ID=" + eElement.getElementsByTagName("SUIFT:FLOW_ID").item(0).getTextContent();

                processFlowResult = processStep + "\n" + flowID;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return processFlowResult;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //I want to use this but negative result since the File() parameter need xml file
    String xmlContent = "<company><staff><firstname>yong</firstname><lastname>mook kim</lastname><nickname>mkyong</nickname><salary>100000</salary></staff></company>";
    
    //This is working
    String xmlPath = "C:\\folder1\\sampleReply.xml";
    XmlReader processFlow = new XmlReader();
    String reply = processFlow.showProcessFlowID(xmlPath);
    System.out.println(reply);
}
```

}

Please advise.

TIA

Comment: Can you please post the entire code that is working for path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.You can user xml string to parse.

```
String xmlStr="";
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStr.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```